# Why can we use *waiting* (present participle) with *grew* (past simple)?

Tags: present-participles

Why can we use *waiting* (present participle) with *grew* (past simple)?

> The children, waiting for the play to begin, **grew** bored.

Sentence is from [Participial Phrase Worksheet at Sinclair.edu](http://www.sinclair.edu/centers/tlc/pub/handouts_worksheets/grammar_punctuation_writing/phrase_participial.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the sentence does NOT mean:

```
The children **are waiting** for the play to begin.
```

Instead it should be *understood* as:

> While the children **were waiting** for the play to begin, they **grew** bored.

You can rewrite the sentence and not change its meaning to:

> The children **were waiting** for the play to begin `but` **grew** bored.

Comment: Stoney:B replied to a similar question and gave an answer [**here**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7262/1694)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the name, the present participle doesn't express something happening in the present, nor does it alter a phrase expressing something happening in the present.

Participial phrases like the following can be used to alter a phrase talking of the past.

> Taking the ferry across the harbor, I saw the Statue of Liberty come into view.

You could rephrase it as follows.

> When I took the ferry across the harbor, I saw the Statue of Liberty come into view.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence shows the use of a **non-essential participial phrase**. I have the non-essential participial phrase from the original sentence in italics to better show the sentence construction.

> The children, *waiting for the play to begin*, grew bored.

Structure: `Subject + , + non-essential participial phrase + , + verb.`

The confusion you face is because the pronoun-verb pair *who were* is implied in the sentence rather than explicitly written, as is often the case for non-essential participial phrases. Here I have included it in bold and you can more clearly see the meaning of the sentence.

> The children,  ***who were*** waiting for the play to begin, grew bored.

Resources for non-essential phrases:
[Perdue Commas with Nonessential Elements](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/05/)
[Essential and Non-Essential Participial Phrases Introduction](http://www.edmondschools.net/Portals/0/docs/ParticipialPhrases.pdf)